# Laravel returning multiple views

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to return multiple views using the laravel framework. When I return the variable, it only makes it through the loop once, therefore only one comment is displayed on the page.

```
foreach($index_comments as $comments){
                        $commentComment = $comments->comment;

                        $index_children = NULL;
                        $getUser = DB::table('users')->where('id', '=', $comments->from_user_id)->get();
                        foreach ($getUser as $user) {
                            $firstName = $user->first_name;
                            $lastName = $user->last_name;
                        }
                        return View::make('feeds.comments')->with(array(
                                'firstName' => $firstName,
                                'lastName' => $lastName,
                                'commentComment' => $commentComment,
                                'index_children' => $index_children
                        ));

                    }
```

I just need a way of returning multiple views.
Thanks for any help!
Toby.

Comment: There is no such thing as "returning multiplpe views" - what exactly are you trying to achieve? Display all comments and the name of the user each comment is from?

Comment: @Quasdunk Yes. I mean I could technically just echo out the values, but I want to try and use the View. I've heard about nesting views but not really sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you don't quite understand the concepts of Laravel and/or PHP yet. So let's start it from scratch: We want to fetch all comments, output the comment and the name of the user who wrote the comment.

At a very basic level, we can just grab it straight from the DB with the query builder:

```
public function showComments() 
{
    $commentData = DB::table('comments')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'comments.from_user_id')
        ->get(['text', 'firstName', 'lastName']);

    return View::make('feeds.comments')->with('commentData', $commentData)
}
```

And in your view:

```
@foreach($commentData as $comment)
    {{ $comment->text }}
    <br />
    written by {{ $comment->firstName }} {{ $comment->lastName }}
    <hr />
@endforeach
```

That's it. You don't return the view on each iteration, the iteration happens in the view. The return statement terminates the function execution immediately. If you return within in a loop, it will always exit upon the first iteration, that's why you're getting only one result.

In the next step, you should play around with Models and [Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent) for even more powerful and readable data handling.